# Errors were encountered while processing: initramfs-tools

Tags: dpkg

After I upgrade my system, it gives the following error-

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.120ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-36-generic
cp: omitting directory ‘/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules’
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-36-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
initramfs-tools
```

The output of **apt-cache policy initramfs-tools** is

```
initramfs-tools:
Installed: 0.120ubuntu6
Candidate: 0.120ubuntu6
Version table:
*** 0.120ubuntu6 0
    500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 0.103ubuntu15 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```